# Dúvida sobre consumir backend com Spring

Tags: java, ionic, spring-boot, heroku

Bom dia,

estou querendo iniciar um projeto de Spring com ionic meu objetivo é publicar o app ionic na loja da Google e consumir o backend com Springboot, sei que tem como consumir esse backend pelo Heroku.

Mas gostaria de saber se subindo o App pra loja teria como eu consumir esse backend em um servidor privado, ou local...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Heroku não tem influência alguma sob os serviços back-end.
Ele é apenas uma forma de hospedar sua aplicação Java/Spring.

Para o aplicativo móvel, o que importa são as rotas dos serviços disponibilizados pelo back-end.

Se você tiver um domínio próprio, você pode configurá-lo onde quiser (inclusive no Heroku) e então chamar os serviços a partir daí.
Dessa forma, não importa se você usa o Heroku ou um servidor próprio. O importante é que as rotas que o aplicativo móvel requisita estejam corretas.

Por exemplo:

Se você tiver o domínio `meudominio.com.br` e que tenha um serviço back-end de cadastro de usuário, seu aplicativo móvel chamaria uma rota como:

```
https://www.meudominio.com.br/usuarios
```

Isso independe se o back-end está no Heroku ou local, desde que a sua escolha esteja configurada corretamente.

Todavia, você não precisa de um domínio particular, mas nesse caso, a rota mudaria conforme a hospedagem que escolher: o Heroku vai ter fornecer algo como `nome-da-sua-app.herokuapp.com`, o local seria um IP, a Amazon teria outra forma e assim por diante.

É claro que é muito mais fácil você subir uma aplicação Spring Boot e configurar o domínio pelo Heroku do que se quiser fazer isso em um servidor próprio (a não ser que você tenha conhecimentos em infra).

Comment: perfeito ! kkkk

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendo você teria que publicar as duas aplicaçãoes.
O aplicativo na loja google e o backend com os web services num servidor que suporte o spring boot.
Com o backend publicado você conseguiria acessá-lo de qualquer lugar.